# how to fetch all friday's on time countdown -react --SOLVED

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a time countdown component but i need a 'every friday -  current time' this structure.
In my build, I have a function that counts down only when I enter the deadline.

here is demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-browser-bvb7rx

solved: here is solved case (just next fridays) codes:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
class DateCountdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      days: 0,
      hours: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 0
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getTimeUntil(this.props.deadline);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.getTimeUntil(this.props.deadline), 1000);
  }
  leading0(num) {
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
  }
  getTimeUntil(deadline) {
    const time = Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
    if (time < 0) {
      this.setState({ days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
    } else {
      const seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60);
      const minutes = Math.floor((time / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      const hours = Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      const days = Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      this.setState({ days, hours, minutes, seconds });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        {" "}
        <div className="Clock-days">{this.leading0(this.state.days)}d</div>{" "}
        <div className="Clock-hours">{this.leading0(this.state.hours)}h</div>
        <div className="Clock-minutes">
          {this.leading0(this.state.minutes)} Min
        </div>
        <div className="seconds">{this.leading0(this.state.seconds)} Sec</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DateCountdown;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the deadline for the following Friday you can generate it:

```
function getFridayOfCurrentWeek() {
  const today = new Date();
  const firstDayOfThisWeek = today.getDate() - today.getDay() + 1;
  const fifthDayOfThisWeek = firstDayOfThisWeek + 4;
  const currentFriday= new Date(today.setDate(fifthDayOfThisWeek));
  return currentFriday;
}
```

getDate gives you the day of the month from 1 - 31

getDay gives you the day of the week from 0 - 6

Subtracting the day of the week from the month and adding 1 gives us the current Monday. Adding 4 to that gives us the Friday we are looking to use as the deadline.